# When does it have real roots and when does it have complex roots?

Tags: complex-numbers

When does this equation has

$${z^4 + mz^2 + n = 0}$$
(given that $m$ and $n$ are real numbers)

a) purely real roots?

b) not has real roots? (I think this one means: it has only roots in the form $a + bi$ and $bi$)

c) has real roots and complex roots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Let $u=z^{2}$, and you will get a quadratic equation, which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

First step $z^2=\frac{-m\pm\sqrt{m^2-4n}}{2}$.

a)To get all real roots requires $z^2\ge 0$ for both signs of the radical and discriminant $\ge 0$.  So $m\lt 0$ and $m^2\ge 4n$.

b) $m^2-4n\lt 0$.

c) $m^2-4n \ge 0$ and $m\gt 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I need to do it again, because I don't want to memorize your answers 